# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I need to run that hook which fetch documents with currentUser.uid names but it fails. The hook starts before i get currentUser so basically it starts when the currentUser is null. Also i can't understand such behaviour.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')
Source
src/layout/SideBar/index.tsx (29:22) @ SideBar

Context:

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      (user) => user && setCurrentUser(user)
    );

    return () => unsub();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Component:

```
export const SideBar = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
      setUserChats(doc.data());
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsub();
  }, [currentUser.uid]);


  return (
  ...
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to update the UseEffect in Sidebar so that it doesnt error?

If that is the case, it is erroring because the `currentUser` is null when trying to call `OnSnapshot`

To fix this you can simply check if `currentUser` is not null or undefined inside that `useEffect` and update the dependency array to use a nullable object :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(currentUser !== null && currentUser !== undefined)
    {  
      const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
              setUserChats(doc.data());
              setLoading(false);
            });
        
      return () => unsub();
    }
  }, [currentUser?.uid]);
```

Comment: I already tried that but still get the same error

Comment: Try changing the dependency array to `[currentUser?.uid]`. 
If this doesnt work, can you share a screenshot of what line 29 is inside Sidebar, as Im not sure which use of the variable is causing the issue

Comment: Just use `currentUser` as the `useEffect` hook dependency, and use `currentUser?.uid` as the conditional test in the hook callback.